How to Fix Error If Variable Contains Double Quotes
Batch Script:
@echo Off
:: Works
::set "var=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
::set "var=cmd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe""
::set "var=CMD "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe""

:: Not Works
set "var="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe""

call :GetPath %var%
Echo file is [%file%]
pause& CLS& Exit /b

:GetPath
setlocal
Set "arg=%*"
::if [%arg:~-1%]==["] for %%a in (%arg%) do set "arg=%%~a"
if /I "%~1"=="cmd" (set "file=%arg:~4%") else (set "file=%arg%")
endlocal & set "file=%file%"
exit /b

Why set "var="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"" not works and giving error (autoclose)?
How to fix this?
I mean if %var% contains double quotes.
what do I need to change the code in :GetPath
Thanks.
